# How strong is this function to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, regex, sql-injection

I've done this simple function in javascript to identify strings with a SQL injection in their value.
How strong is it? Which sql attacks break it?

Thanks for your time!

```js
function hasSQL(value) {
    if (_.isNull(value) || _.isUndefined(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    // sql regex reference: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detection-sql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting-attacks
    const sqlMeta = new RegExp('(\%27)|(\')|(\-\-)|(\%23)|(#)', 'i');
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-control-regex
    const sqlMeta2 = new RegExp('((\%3D)|(=))[^\n]*((\%27)|(\')|(\-\-)|(\%3B)|(;))', 'i');
    const sqlTypical = new RegExp('\w*((\%27)|(\'))((\%6F)|o|(\%4F))((\%72)|r|(\%52))', 'i');
    const sqlUnion = new RegExp('((\%27)|(\'))union', 'i');
    const mssqlExec = new RegExp('/exec(\s|\\+)+(s|x)p\w+', "i");
    const inlineOrBlock = new RegExp('.*;[\\t\\r\\n ]*(and )?[\\t\\r\\n ]*(select|insert|update|delete).*', "ig");

    return sqlMeta.test(value) || sqlMeta2.test(value) || sqlTypical.test(value) ||
        sqlUnion.test(value) || mssqlExec.test(value) || value.match(inlineOrBlock);
};
```

Comment: I am not competent to answer the original question but may I ask why you want to perform this check (in js)?

Comment: Sure, the check is done server-side in node.js.

Comment: Your code would prevent me from ever inserting `foo--` into your database, or `#bobby-tables`. Maybe tell us what situation you actually want to prevent, and why you are not using SQL placeholders.

Comment: Our software uses a proprietary ORM that does not use sql statements, so I was wondering if a function of this type could be an alternative, even temporary, to the modification of the classes that builds the sql of the ORM.

Comment: Does the ORM not already do it's own stripping of values?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't test for sql injections, so string values for fields of text type like "testName' and password=''; --//" are executed like "UPDATE users set name='testName' and password=''; --//" can be dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

I only looked at this code briefly. I didn't make a thorough examination of all the conditions, but I see at least this one problem:

```
const sqlUnion = new RegExp('((\%27)|(\'))union', 'i');
```

This wouldn't catch SQL injection that has one or more spaces between the `'` and the `union`.

I'm not suggesting that fixing the regular expressions would make this secure. I'd advise that the *approach of using regular expressions is fundamentally not secure*. There are too many edge cases that could slip through.

It's hard to test for all those cases, and asking for a free code review on Stack Overflow is not a test plan.

There's a well-known solution that is easier and more secure: **Use query parameters.**

You said you're using an ORM that doesn't allow that. I would say the ORM needs to be fixed, or else abandoned. Failure to handle security in the most commonly accepted way makes it a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements and parameterized queries
Although entries could be sanitized using methods such as mysqli_real_escape_string, it is more advisable to use prepared or parameterized sentences.

Example is given below

[Preventing SQL Inject using PHP](https://www.top10solution.com/how-to-avoid-mysql-sql-injection-in-php/)